# How make long time cache in nginx?

Tags: nginx, cache-control, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have an app, that generate a pictures. Before him is Nginx. I need make nginx cache with big value of proxy_cache_valid. I set this value to 365 days. But cache expires in 10 minutes, and my app generate same image again. How make long time nginx cache? Here is my nginx config:

```
proxy_cache_path /var/lib/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=cache:100m max_size=100G;
proxy_temp_path /var/lib/nginx/proxy 1 2;
proxy_ignore_headers Expires Cache-Control;
proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header http_502;
proxy_no_cache $cookie_session;

proxy_cache_bypass $cookie_session $http_x_myupdate;


server {
    server_name conv.site.com ;
    client_max_body_size 32m;

    location / {
        proxy_cache cache;
        proxy_cache_valid 365d
        proxy_cache_valid 404 1m;
        proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires Set-Cookie;

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3021 ;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

}
```

Comment: You are missing a `;` at the end of the `proxy_cache_valid 365d` statement.

Comment: I missing ; in this page. In server config all right. 
thank you for observation